# Spring security filter after request processing

Tags: spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

How can I make my spring security filter get executed after request is processed by Controller/JAX-RS endpoint?

A normal java filter chain is supposed to get control when the request is processed both ways. How to do that with spring security filters? I tried calling `chain.doFilter()` at the start and  adding my logic after the call. However, after request is processed, the control doesn't come back.

Any pointers on how this can be achieved, is it possible with spring security filters at all?

Comment: Filters are executed before servlets. What you want to achieve?

Comment: May be you have some exception during request processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question -

Spring security filter chain processes filters registered with and does not give control back to normal filters configured.

The resolution I used was to define my filters before spring securityFilterChain.